# ¿Problemas con resultado en sql server con tipo de dato numérico?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente código, he probado con los tipos de datos numéricos y solo me retorna 0, quiero que me 60,00 que es el resultado de la cuenta, sin embargo me devuelve 0.

```
DECLARE @DIASTRANS MONEY
  SET @DIASTRANS = (12/20)*100
   select @DIASTRANS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor `0` es debido a la división entre enteros, para ello es necesario que el `divisor` sea un número de coma flotante.

```
DECLARE @DIASTRANS MONEY
SET @DIASTRANS = (CAST(12 AS FLOAT)/CAST(20 AS FLOAT))*100
select @DIASTRANS
```